# Prime factors of a number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization

What will be the mathematical proof of the fact that a number doesn't have $2$ different permutations of prime factors ?

I am unable to think beyond this :

1. Find the floor or ceiling of square root of a number.
2. Get all the prime numbers till the result from 1.

Comment: Are you asking about Unique Factorization?  Not easy to prove, but the argument in Euclid is good.  Easy to find online, known as the [Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic)

Comment: Hint: use Euclid's Lemma (prime $\,p\mid ab\,\Rightarrow\, p\mid a\,$ or $\,p\mid b)\,$ to match up primes in any two factorizations. By cancellation and induction one obtains uniqueness.

Comment: It depends a bit what is your definition for a prime, and what do you know about its properties.

Comment: By prime I mean Prime Number

Comment: @FurquanAhmed yes, but what is you definition of a prime number and what do you know about it. For example do you know the property in B.D.'s comment?

Comment: i just understand that prime number are divisible by themselves or by 1 , and from @BillDubuque comment i understand that if ab is divisible by p then p either divides a or p divides b or it can do both too !! am i correct ?

Comment: @FurquanAhmed Stillwell calls the property that I mentioned the *Prime Divisor Property* and he proves it using the Bezout identity for the gcd in Section 3.3 (standard proof). Then he uses it to prove uniqueness in the way that I hinted. You can find the same proof in almost any elementary number theory textbook (and in many prior answers here).

Comment: ok, thank you, I will read that !!! :)